# How to do extra spacing when using small caps for abbreviations?

Tags: spacing, small-caps, microtype

The default letter spacing for small capitals seem optimised for use in headlines and such but a bit too cramped for use in abbreviations. How should I do to get the letter spacing more suitably bigger for abbreviations?

Also, I am using the `memoir` class and `\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [microtype](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/microtype.html) package and its `tracking` option. Use the `letterspace` option for finetuning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

\usepackage[%
%  tracking=smallcaps,
%  letterspace=50,% default: 100
]{microtype}

\newcommand*{\abbrev}[1]{\textls[50]{\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\Huge

Some text \textsc{in small caps}.

Some text \abbrev{in small caps}.

\end{document}
```

EDIT: While some of `microtype`'s features (notably automatic font expansion) don't work with bitmap fonts, tracking/letterspacing may work. I haven't tested this thoroughly, though.

EDIT 2: Example modified in order to letterspace only within specific macro.

Comment: Hm, this is going to change all small caps, right? It's actually only in abbreviations the spacing needs to be changed. For headings and such it's fine as it is.

Comment: Hm actually it seems not: ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.

Comment: @jonalv: I updated my example. (It also works with mathpazo.)

Answer (score 4):

I would rather use the soul package. You can define a macro to make it easier to typeset the abbreviations as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{soul}

%\usepackage[%
%  tracking=smallcaps,
%  letterspace=50,% default: 100
%]{microtype}

\def\abbreviation#1{\textsc{\so{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\textsc{nato}

\abbreviation{nato}
\end{document}
```

Uncomment the `microtype` package code above to see the differences.

Comment: Hm we posted almost simultaneosly. Your example does however not fine tune the spacing and the default from your example is giganormous! :)

Comment: @jonalv ... it happens, but I am glad you found the solution to your problem. Did not post any settings being confident that you would be interested in reading the manual. Some good settings can be found in the `tufte-book` class. Search for the definition of `newthought`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the soul package because it seemed microtype did not work with the font I was using:

(Edit: apparantly it was possible to get it to work though)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\abbrev}[1]{\null\so{\textsc{#1}}\null}

\begin{document}
\sodef\so{}{0.1em }{0em}{0em}

So now I can write \abbrev{usa} instead of \textsc{usa}.

\end{document}
```